# SQL sum of order value from joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the sum of sales of every order, along with customer and employee details from another table

**Order Details table**

```
OrderID ProductID   UnitPrice   Quantity    Discount
10248   11              10         1              0
10248   42              20         2              0
10248   72              20         3              0
10249   14              10         1              0
10249   51              40         2              0
```

**Orders table**

```
OrderID CustomerName    EmployeeName
10248   C1               E1
10249   C2               E2
```

Desired result

```
orderid sales   Customer   Employee
10248   110        C1        E1
10249    90        C2        E2
```

So I need total sum of sales for each order (e.g. 10248 order has sales 10*1 + 20*2 + 20*3 = 10+40+60=110) and corresponding employee name and customer name

**Query tried**

```
select od.orderid, Unitprice * Quantity as sales 
group by od.orderid
From [Order Details] od
inner join orders o on od.orderid = o.orderid
```

**Error:**

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'From'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate by order, and then take the *sum* of the sales per order:

```
SELECT
    od.orderid,
    SUM(Unitprice * Quantity) AS sales 
FROM [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN orders o
    ON od.orderid = o.orderid
GROUP BY
    od.orderid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, you are having a `group by` before `from`. Also you do not need to do `group by` if you are using no aggregation instead you can use `distinct.`

```
select 
  od.orderid, 
  sum(Unitprice * Quantity) as sales 
From [Order Details] od    
inner join orders o on od.orderid=o.orderid 
group by
   od.orderid
```

Comment: There is an error in this code. `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column 'Order Details.UnitPrice' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column 'Order Details.Quantity' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor what error are you getting? could you please check the updated one?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor updated my code, please check.

Comment: now it works...but its same as above answer wo answered first.....

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` belongs before `GROUP BY`.

```
select od.orderid, unitprice * quantity as sales 
from [Order Details] od
group by od.orderid;
```

With the order information joined:

```
select o.orderid, od.sales, o.customername, o.employeename
from orders o
join
(
  select orderid, unitprice * quantity as sales
  from [Order Details]
  group by orderid
) od on od.orderid = o.orderid
order by o.orderid;
```

Comment: I need customer details and employee details too, so have to join

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I've updated my answer. I am aggregating before joining, which should not be necessary here, but is considered good style and often even necessary when working with multiple aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM()` in conjuction with `GROUP BY`. I am incapable of testing but code like this should work on most SQL versions.

```
SELECT 
   od.orderid, 
   SUM(od.Unitprice * od.Quantity) as sales,
   ot.CustomerName,
   ot.EmployeeName
FROM od
INNER JOIN ot ON od.orderid=ot.orderid;
GROUP BY od.orderid;
```

You should be able to adapt the script to your database.